# WCF REST Service client data Post Error with More than 8200 characters

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

I am using WCF REST Service and unable to post more value with more than 8200 characters.

I am getting  Bad Response 400

```
var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response = client.Post(uri.ToString(),HttpContentExtensions.CreateJsonDataContract(value));
```

I have also added following in web.config.

```
 <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000" maxBufferSize="2000000" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're liking hitting the `maxStringContentLength` quota (default = 8192). If this is the case, you should increase the quota in the standard endpoint as shown below. But to find out for sure, try enabling tracing at the server, the traces will have an exception saying exactly why the server rejected the request.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
      <standardEndpoint name=""
                        helpEnabled="true"
                        automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"
                        maxBufferSize="2000000"
                        maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000">
        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2000000"/>
      </standardEndpoint>
    </webHttpEndpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: GREAT carlosfigueira !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
that was a million dollar solution. Worked for me....:)